# Numbers after a draft format

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-online

Most drafts that I have seen on MTGO use a set of numbers after the format. I think it describes what matches are played after the drafting portion. For example:

> Modern Masters 2015 6-2-2-2<sup>[[1]](http://magic.wizards.com/en/MTGO/articles/archive/magic-online/modern-masters-2015-edition-event-schedule-2015-05-04#MM26222)</sup>

Modern Masters 2015 refers to the types of boosters that will be opened. What does the "6-2-2-2" mean?

I have also seen "8-4" as a common postfix. Are there others, and if so what do they mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must be referring to MTGO (the online version of the game). You generally enter a draft with seven other players (for a total of eight). The postfix refers to how many packs you will receive when the tournament is over.

The postfix "6-2-2-2" indicates three rounds of Swiss. Swiss means that you will continue to play whether you win or lose. After three rounds of 6-2-2-2 are completed:

- One player will have three wins. That player receives six packs.
- Three players will have two wins. They will each receive two packs.

The postfix "8-4" indicates three rounds of single elimination. This means that when you lose, you are out. After three rounds of 8-4 are completed:

- One player will be the winner. That player receives eight packs.
- One player will be the runner-up. That player receives four packs.

This is described in more detail on [the Wizards of the Coast website](http://magic.wizards.com/en/MTGO/articles/archive/magic-online/modern-masters-2015-edition-event-schedule-2015-05-04#MM26222) (which I just noticed you also linked to in the question).

Answer (score 5):

That is the prize payout.

First place receives 6 booster packs, 2nd 3rd and 4th receive 2 each.  (Or first place receives 8 and second receives 4, in the other example.)

If you scroll down a bit on your link it's written out in a table.

Answer (score 1):

That is the prize payout. 6-2-2-2 means 1st place will get 6 packs, and 2nd - 4th will get 2 packs each. 8-4 means first gets 8 packs, 2nd gets 4. This is shown underneath under the Prizes section on the page you linked to.

> 3 Wins **6 Modern Masters 2015 Edition booster packs**
>   2 Wins **2 Modern Masters 2015 Edition booster packs**

With a normal 3 round, 8 person draft, assuming no ties you will end up with 1 person with 3 wins, and 3 with 2 wins (and 3 with 1 win and 1 with 0 wins, though they don't get any prizes in a 6-2-2-2 tournament)